# ¿Cómo puedo hacer funcional mi BottomNavMenu?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

He estado intentando hacer funcional mi BottomNavMenu, pero me sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> He intentado cambiar los errores, pero no lo he conseguido. En otro programa por ejemplo sí he sido capaz de lograrlo.

Dejo el código de la actividad:

```
class MenuPrincipalActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

var BottomNavigationView : BottomNavigationView ?= null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_principal)
    BottomNavigationView=this.findViewById(R.id.bottomAppBar)
    BottomNavigationView?.background ?: null
    BottomNavigationView?.menu?.getItem(2)?.isEnabled = false

    val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

    val homeFragment = HomeFragment()
    val favFragment = FavFragment()
    val chatFragment = ChatFragment()
    val settingsFragment = SettingsFragment()

    makeCurrentFragment(homeFragment)

    BottomNavigationView!!.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        when (it.itemId){
            R.id.navigation_home -> makeCurrentFragment(homeFragment)
            R.id.navigation_fav -> makeCurrentFragment(favFragment)
            R.id.navigation_chat -> makeCurrentFragment(chatFragment)
            R.id.navigation_settings -> makeCurrentFragment(settingsFragment)
        }
        true
    }
}

private fun makeCurrentFragment(fragment: Fragment) =
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
        replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment)
        commit()
    }
```

}

Comment: la view que tiene el id `R.id.bottomAppBar` es un `BottomAppBar` y estás intentando asignarla a una variable de tipo `BottomNavigationView`. El error es que no coinciden los tipos

Answer (score 0):

El error está en que hay que poner

```
        BottomNavigationView=this.findViewById(R.id.BottomNavigationView)
```

En vez de

```
    BottomNavigationView=this.findViewById(R.id.bottomAppBar)
```